# Read value over time at certain coordinate from netCDF with python

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a netCDF file with a grid (each step 0.25°).
What I want is the value of the variable, lets say tempMax, at a certain gridpoint, over the last 50 years.

I am aware that you read the data into python like this

```
lon = numpy.array(file.variables['longitude'][:])
lat = numpy.array(file.variables['latitude'][:])
temp = numpy.array(file.variables['tempMax'][:])
time = numpy.array(file.variables['time'][:])
```

That leaves me with an array and I do not know how to "untangle" it.
How to get the value at a certain coordinate (stored in temp) over the whole time (stored in time)?
S display is the value over the time at the certain coordinate.

Any ideas how I could achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that `tempMax` is 3D (time x lat x lon) and should then be read in as

```
temp = ncfile.variables['tempMAx'][:,:,:]
```

(Note two things: (1) if you're using Python v2, it's best to avoid the word `file` and instead use something like `ncfile` as shown above, (2) `temp` will be automatically stored as a `numpy.ndarray` simply with the call above, you don't need to use the `numpy.array()` command during the read in of variables.)

Now you can extract temperatures for all times at a certain location with

```
temp_crd = temp[:,lat_idx,lon_idx]
```

where `lat_idx` and `lon_idx` are integers corresponding to the index of the latitude and longitude coordinates.  If you know these indices beforehand, great, just plug them in, e.g. `temp_crd = temp[:,25,30]`. (You can use the tool `ncdump` to view the contents of a netCDF file, https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/ncdump.html)

The more likely case is that you know the coordinates, but not their indices beforehand.  Let's say you want temperatures at 50N and 270E.  You can use the `numpy.where` function to extract the indices of the coordinates given the `lat` and `lon` arrays that you've already read in.

```
lat_idx = numpy.where(lat==50)[0][0]
lon_idx = numpy.where(lon==270)[0][0]

tmp_crd = temp[:,lat_idx,lon_idx]
```